# Exact conditions so that vector-space-like change of basis is possible in a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, change-of-basis, free-modules

This is a follow-up of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727605/change-of-basis-in-general-free-modules) question. Suppose $R$ is a *unital* ring that is *not* necessarily with the IBN property, and $M$ a nontivial *free* left $R$-module with a basis $B$.

> **Under what exact conditions**, for every injective $R$-module endomorphism $h: M\to M$, the set $h(B)$ is a new basis?

For $M$ a *finitely generated* free left $R$-module, we have

> **Lemma 1.** For an injective endomorphism $h:M\to M$, the set $h(B)$ is a new basis *iff* the map $h$ is surjective (hence invertible).

For $R$ a unital *commutative* ring, we further have

> **Lemma 2.** For a finitely generated free left $R$-module $M$ over a unital commutative ring $R$, an $R$-module endomorphism $h: M\to M$ is injective *iff* the determinant $\det(h)$ is not a zero-divisor in $R$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3743717/416552), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080215/416552), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71741/416552) for the proofs.)

Based on the two lemmas, the following *might* be true.

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a non-zero finitely generated free left $R$-module  over a unital commutative ring $R$, and $B\subset M$ a basis. Then, the image of $B$ by every injective endomorphism of $M$ is a basis of $M$ *iff* the ring $R$ only consists of units and zero-divisors.

*Proof.* For every injective endomorphism $h$, by lemma 2, $\det(h)$ is not a zero-divisor. If $R$ consists of only units and zero-divisors, then $\det(A)$ is a unit, and so $h$ is invertible. By lemma 1, $h(B)$ is then a basis.

Conversely, if $h$ is an endomorphism and $h(B)$ is a basis, then $h$ is invertible by lemma 1, and so $\det(A)$ is a unit. If this is true for every injective endomorphism $h$, then by lemma 2, every element in $R$ that is not a zero-divisor must be a unit. $\square$

**But I'm not sure how to answer when $R$ is noncommutative.** Thanks in advance.

**Update:** With a helpful comment, the proposition would clearly be false for infinitely-generated free modules.

Comment: 1) In your proof of Lemma 3, do not use [the symbol $\aleph,$ which already has a precise meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number). 2) In your final question, specify "free module *with finite basis*", otherwise the answer is too easy.

Comment: 3) In your explicitely non-necessarily-commutative context (since you distinguish between left-zero-divisors and right-zero-divisors), your maps $h_r:m\mapsto rm$ are not endomorphisms of your left module $M.$ Moreover, I cannot see how your proposition should result from the lemmas, more precisely why non-units should be right-zero-divisors. I think you should better restrict to commutative rings.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. I'll try to phrase it better. I don't understand why $h_r: m\mapsto rm$ is not an endomorphism. Isn't $h_r$ a module homomorphism from $M$ to itself?

Comment: If $rs\ne sr$, $h_r(sm)\ne sh_r(m)$ in general.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, right. But if restricted to commutative rings, then the lemmas imply the proposition, correct? Becuase lemma 2 applies to all injective endomorphisms, and the $h_r$'s are special ones. If $M$ is also finitely generated, then $A: M\to M$ is injective *iff* $\det(A)$ is not a zero-devisor. So if the ring only consists of units and zero-divisors, then all the injective $A$'s automatically are invertible. That makes the condition sufficient.

Comment: @AnneBauval Perhaps I didn't express my question clearly enough. What I want to ask is: if $B$ is a basis, then under what conditions is $f(B)$ guaranteed to be also a basis, where $f: M\to M$ is an arbitrary injective endomorphism. So I shouldn't have started from equal cardinality. I'll update it.

Comment: Yes, if restricted to commutative rings, everything was ok for me (you should just clarify this from the beginning, and only speak of zero-divisors, not mentionning left/right/two-sided). As for your question, it was clear and my answer would have been the same as yours, reasoning on determinant, once you would have agreed to restrict to *commutative* rings, and to the case of free modules with *finite* basis. So there is no question left. But the new question with which you intend to replace the now solved one is too vague, imo.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks. I updated. Does it all make sense now? I hope there's no mistakes left.

Comment: For non-finitely generated it never happens. If $B$ is a basis, then $B$ is infinite, so there exists a non-surjective embedding $f\colon B\to B$. Then $f$ extends to an injective endomorphism of $M$ which is not surjective; in particular, $f(B)$ cannot be a basis, since it doesn't even span.

Comment: This is exactly the reason of the advice 2) of my first comment above. @ArturoMagidin (and user760: please follow it by editing your last sentence).

Comment: @user760 Also, your proposition is not well-phrased because of the quantifiers. It is not true that "if $B\subset M$ is a basis and $h: M\to M$ an injective endomorphism, then the set $h(B)$ is also a basis *iff* The ring $R$ consists of only units and zero-divisors" (take $h=id$ and $R=$ any ring). Instead, write something like "For a finitely generated free left $R$-module $M$ with basis $B$ over a unital commutative ring $R$, the image of $B$ by *every* injective endomorphism of $M$ is a basis of $M$ *iff* the ring $R$ consists of only units and zero-divisors";

Comment: Or simply (without reference to $B$): "[...] every injective endomorphism of $M$ is bijective *iff* the ring $R$ consists only of units and zero-divisors". Btw, $M$ must moreover be assumed to be non-zero.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! I'll update. Yes, at the beginning of the post, I assumed $M$ to be "nontrivial".

Comment: Although you added the word "every", your proposition remains ambiguous at best (and false at worst).

Comment: Your proposition remains ambiguous at best (and false at worst): "$(\forall h\dots)$ [the image h(B)
 is also a basis iff The ring R
 consists...]"

Comment: @AnneBauval I did seem to find a potential mistake in the attempted proof. But I'm not sure how to phrase the (potentially false) proposition better. You are welcome to edit it.

Comment: There is no essential mistake, and every element of $R$ is obviously a $\det.$ The only "mistake" was the wording of the propostion.